# expire my playstore account

Tags: android, google-play, google-account

If my publishing developer account gets expired, than what will happens to my already published application. Will they removed all my applications or my applications will remains live? What if applications are paid, can I able to change the price?

Comment: a year o.O i thought it was lifetime, let me check again. Since it has been more thatn 1 year i have been using and it did not expire

Comment: it is not 25$/year, 25$ is registration fee, not subscription.

Comment: so are you able to publish new apps after a year ? No need to renew your membership.

Comment: no need to renew, it is not subscription. You register once and goes to lifetime

Comment: Thanks. I was just confused that it is kinda subscription.

Comment: plz give reason for down vote. don't just click on down vote button .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unlike Windows and iOS where developer is been charged every year(100$), android developer has to pay one time fee that is 25$ and then no further charge or fee.

But yes account termination due to various content policies, that can ban your account and your account will expire as it is.

and for reference you can check this [link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2491922?hl=en).

Comment: if my account expired due to any reason, then what will happed to my published application.

Comment: First account never expires, it can get banned so if your developer account gets banned all your published apps will be removed from the playstore.

Comment: are you sure about this? Is there any documentation regarding this? Please let me know if there is any.

Comment: dont know about the documentation, but i am 352% sure about what i said above

Comment: you can check [Link](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/2491922?hl=en) for further reference

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Developer accounts last forever as it wouldn't be profitable for small developers to make recurring payments. The only way for you to "expire" an account is getting banned/terminated. Then all apps you publish will get removed.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Developer accounts does not expire but if Google Play Developer Console account owner has added you as developer then Access to the developer console may expire.

[image: Access to the Google developer console may expire.]

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022:

Google Play Developer accounts does not expire if you have at least 1 app on draft/published, otherwise the developer account will be terminated because Google consider it abandoned due inactivity.